# The Magic Letter H

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, calculation-puzzle

Place seven different positive integers on the empty disks of the H figure below so that the product of the three numbers in any straight black line is always the same. Now place seven other numbers in the disks of a similar H so that the products are again equal, but precisely one more than on the first case.

**What is the least those products can be?**

[image]

Comment: Do the seven other numbers have to be entirely different from the first set? Like if you had 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in the first set and 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 would that be allowed?

Comment: @gabbo1092: Inevitably they will be otherwise products will not be consecutive.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos unless they share a 1.

Comment: Does "in any straight line" include the diagonals, or just along the black lines?

Comment: @hexomino: just along black lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By brute force:

> First H with product 225:
>
> ```
>   9     3
>   1 45  5
>  25    15
> ```
>
> and second H with product 224:
>
> ```
>   1     7
>  14  2  8
>  16     4
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>   1     8
>  16  2  7
>  14     4
> ```

Comment: Three Magic H's with consecutive products can be construct using numbers 1274, 1275, 1276. Their existence is related to Ramanujan's highly composite numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here are consecutive Magic H´s of lengths 2, 3, ..., 8:

224 ((2, 7, 16), (1, 4, 56), (1, 2, 112))

225 ((3, 5, 15), (1, 9, 25), (1, 3, 75))

---

1274 ((2, 13, 49), (1, 7, 182), (1, 2, 637))

1275 ((3, 17, 25), (1, 5, 255), (1, 3, 425))

1276 ((2, 11, 58), (1, 4, 319), (1, 2, 638))

---

9162 ((2, 9, 509), (1, 3, 3054), (1, 2, 4581))

9163 ((7, 17, 77), (1, 11, 833), (1, 7, 1309))

9164 ((2, 29, 158), (1, 4, 2291), (1, 2, 4582))

9165 ((3, 13, 235), (1, 5, 1833), (1, 3, 3055))

---

17574 ((2, 29, 303), (1, 3, 5858), (1, 2, 8787))

17575 ((5, 37, 95), (1, 19, 925), (1, 5, 3515))

17576 ((2, 13, 676), (1, 4, 4394), (1, 2, 8788))

17577 ((3, 9, 651), (1, 7, 2511), (1, 3, 5859))

17578 ((2, 17, 517), (1, 11, 1598), (1, 2, 8789))

---

63423 ((3, 27, 783), (1, 9, 7047), (1, 3, 21141))

63424 ((2, 8, 3964), (1, 4, 15856), (1, 2, 31712))

63425 ((5, 43, 295), (1, 25, 2537), (1, 5, 12685))

63426 ((2, 11, 2883), (1, 3, 21142), (1, 2, 31713))

63427 ((7, 17, 533), (1, 13, 4879), (1, 7, 9061))

63428 ((2, 101, 314), (1, 4, 15857), (1, 2, 31714))

---

179330 ((2, 79, 1135), (1, 5, 35866), (1, 2, 89665))

179331 ((3, 113, 529), (1, 23, 7797), (1, 3, 59777))

179332 ((2, 107, 838), (1, 4, 44833), (1, 2, 89666))

179333 ((7, 17, 1507), (1, 11, 16303), (1, 7, 25619))

179334 ((2, 9, 9963), (1, 3, 59778), (1, 2, 89667))

179335 ((5, 31, 1157), (1, 13, 13795), (1, 5, 35867))

179336 ((2, 29, 3092), (1, 4, 44834), (1, 2, 89668))

---

294590 ((2, 89, 1655), (1, 5, 58918), (1, 2, 147295))

294591 ((3, 79, 1243), (1, 11, 26781), (1, 3, 98197))

294592 ((2, 8, 18412), (1, 4, 73648), (1, 2, 147296))

294593 ((13, 31, 731), (1, 17, 17329), (1, 13, 22661))

294594 ((2, 37, 3981), (1, 3, 98198), (1, 2, 147297))

294595 ((5, 19, 3101), (1, 7, 42085), (1, 5, 58919))

294596 ((2, 47, 3134), (1, 4, 73649), (1, 2, 147298))

294597 ((3, 27, 3637), (1, 9, 32733), (1, 3, 98199))